# Shared Preferences not saving when I compile my code

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using sharedpreferences to store my players highscore. The highscore function works, and the highscore saves, but when I make a change to my code, the players highscore is reset to 0. I am worried about this because if I have to update in the future it will restart my players scores.

```
public void highscoreSaver() {

    if(finalScore > SharedPrefManager.getHighScore()) {
        SharedPrefManager.SetHighScore(finalScore);             
        SharedPrefManager.StoreToPref();
        }

}
```

SharedPrefManager.java:

```
package com.divergent.thumbler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

// all methods are static , so we can call from any where in the code
//all member variables are private, so that we can save load with our own fun only
public class SharedPrefManager {
//this is your shared preference file name, in which we will save data
public static final String MY_EMP_PREFS = "MySharedPref";  

//saving the context, so that we can call all 
//shared pref methods from non activity classes. 
//because getSharedPreferences required the context.
//but in activity class we can call without this context
private static Context     mContext; 

// will get user input in below variables, then will store in to shared pref
private static int         HighScore;

public static void Init(Context context)
{
    mContext         = context;
}
public static void LoadFromPref()
{
    SharedPreferences settings     = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0);
    // Note here the 2nd parameter 0 is the default parameter for private access,
    //Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation,
    settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);

}
public static void StoreToPref()
{
    // get the existing preference file
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt("HighScore", HighScore); // Age is the key and mAge is holding the value

    //final step to commit (save)the changes in to the shared pref
    editor.commit(); 
}

public static void DeleteSingleEntryFromPref(String keyName)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove(keyName);
    editor.commit();
}

public static void DeleteAllEntriesFromPref()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}


public static void SetHighScore(int score)
{
    HighScore = score;
}

public static int getHighScore()
{
    return HighScore ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never setting the `HighScore` integer to a value. I think maybe you think this line is doing something different than it actually is:

```
settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);
```

This calls the getInt function, which returns the value that has a key in the first paramater. If the value doesn't exist in the shared preferences, it returns HighScore instead. What you probably want is this:

```
HighScore = settings.getInt("HighScore", 0)
```

This will set HighScore to the value in the settings under "HighScore". If there is no value, then it'll return 0.

Make sure you also call `LoadFromPref()` if you're going to call `getHighScore()`!

Comment: That doesnt seem to be my issue. The highscore works just fine. When I re open the app and check the highscore its correct, but whenever I make changes to my code it resets to 0.

Comment: What happens if you turn the device on and off? I suspect that when you close and reopen the app, android hasn't actually terminated it. Android doesn't kill off apps as soon as you go to another app -- it only does so if you open enough new apps that it runs out of resources. If you restart the phone, you'll force Android to actually stop running the app. I suspect that you'll see the same issue, and the score will reset to 0.

Comment: It did that yes, so what is my issue?

Comment: Then the issue is that it's not reloading the preference properly, and not that it's an issue with updating the code. Try making the suggestions I suggested initially and let me know how that works for ya!

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences used to store application level values. Whenever you do changes to code and again run the application, it creates shared preferences as new file & all previous data gets reset.

**If you want score even after making some code changes and re-running application. It is better to store score in a file or DB and avoid creating file or copy database if it already exists in device. So that always you can get that data anytime. You can use content providers also.**

Comment: Could you provide documentation?

Comment: Documentation related to exactly which process??

Comment: to store a score in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I wrote for shared prefrences. It works fine in a simple game I am working on. You can simply use this singleton in your activity where you need to set/fetch the games high score. I use it for default shared prefrences, but it can also be used for multiple prefrences if needed.

```
 /**
  * 
  *         This class is used for reading / writing data to a single prefrences
  *         file.
  * 
  *         Simply use setHighScore and getHighScore to get the score from a
  *         single prefrences file
  * 
  */
public enum SharedPrefrencesUtil {

UTIL;

private final String HIGH_SCORE = "HighScore";

/**
 * Gets a single shared prefrences file
 */
public SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreference(Activity activity) {
    return activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

/**
 * Gets a specific shared preferences file if there are multiples in the application 
 */
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String preferenceFileName,
        Context context) {

    return context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

/**
 * Sets a score into a the default prefrences file
 */
public void setScore(Activity activity, int score){
    activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(HIGH_SCORE, score).commit();
}

/**
 * Gets the score from the default prefrences file
 */
public int getHighScore(Activity activity) {
    return activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(HIGH_SCORE, 0);

}

}
```